# Reading a value from a properties file and using that value in .less file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, less

I have a Spring MVC web application. I want to have a single properties file where all the hex value for colors will be defined.

```
blue=#0000FF
green=#008000
//other colors defined here.
```

Is there a way with which I can read these color values and use them when required in .less file?

Eg.

```
mysamplefile.less

.background-color-green { background-color: //read green from properties file and use it here }
.background-color-blue { background-color: //read blue from properties file and use it here }
```

Comment: Why not define these colors at the top of your `less` file?

Comment: @Oliver: I want to these color hex values in java (and then use them is jsp, js files). I want to avoid having multiple files where these color hex values are hardcoded.

Comment: I suppose you can modify the `LESS` compiler to accomplish this? I did this with `SASS` a while ago, but can't find the code. Maybe it can be done with `LESS`.